# Wrong scaled up icon in taskbar of a Win32 application on Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a UI C++ Win32/WTL app. I have an application icon with many embedded sizes, including 16x16, 32x32, 48x48 and 64x64. I do a `SetIcon()` for both small and large icons and yet my Windows 7 task bar shows a blurry scaled up icon.

Are there any special APIs that need to be called or some special considerations?

Answer (score 1):

The icon shown in the taskbar is not the one you set with SetIcon() but the one that explorer also shows for the exe file itself. That means it shows the very first icon in your exe resources.
Change the resource ID of your icon to e.g. 1 so it's the first icon, or add other sizes to the first icon your exe currently uses.

Answer (score 0):

Icons are in the order? I have information, that Windows use icons in direct order. Try place icon 64x64 in the first place in array.

Answer (score 0):

Unusual DPI / font size setting? I've seen XP ask for a 20x20 icon.